# how do i handle special characters scraped from a web page (xml and strings)

Tags: c#, special-characters

using HTMLAgility, C#, XML

I am using HTMLAgility to scrape a web page and in turn populate a class structure that in turn gets serialised into an XML document.

the data I am handling are guitar chords and as such I have some special characters to manage.

the special character I am struggling with is "Aº7" the middle character in the preceding string (which means diminished in musical terms).

when i get the string from the webpage I see a question mark in a black diamond in the watch window, this in turn gets populated in the XML.

my choices are 
a) handle the char appropriately so that it presents in XML as the character it is.
b) convert every instance of this char in a string to the word "dim"

what is the best way to go about this as the char does get found in a replace statement (using char(code)).

I am not really sure how I 'should' approach this problem.

Code below that I am using to grab data (for clarity, this is a once and done function that once i have the data in a usable format will never get used again!, simply built to create an xml serialised object structure).

```
        public void BuildDBFromWebSite()
    {
        string[] chordKeys = { "A", "A#", "Ab", "B", "Bb", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "Db", "E", "Eb", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "Gb" };

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        foreach (string chordKeyName in chordKeys)
        {
            //LOOP THROUGH THE CHORD KEYS
            chordKey theChordKey = new chordKey() { KeyName = chordKeyName };
            _keys.Add(theChordKey);

            //grab the tone page
            doc = web.Load("http://www.scales-chords.com/showchbykey.php?key=" + theChordKey.KeyName);

            HtmlNode chordListTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='body']/div[@id='left']/div[@id='visit']/table/tbody");            

            //  CHORDS
            HtmlNodeCollection chordRows = chordListTable.SelectNodes("tr");

            for (int i = 2; i < chordRows.Count; i++)
            {
                //LOOP THROUGH THE CHORDS
                Chord theChord = new Chord();

                HtmlNodeCollection chordInfoCells = chordRows[i].SelectNodes("td");
                HtmlNode chordLink = chordInfoCells[0].SelectSingleNode("a[@href]");

                //each of the next 3 cells can contain a bad glyph for diminished chords
                theChord.ChordName = chordInfoCells[0].InnerText;
                theChord.ChordNameText = chordInfoCells[1].InnerText;
                theChord.Family = chordInfoCells[2].InnerText;
                theChord.Importance = chordInfoCells[3].InnerText;

                //HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute href = chordLink.Attributes["href"];
                //HTMLAgility tries to encode the bad glyph but uses the wrong escape and breaks the href, work around is to manually strip the href myself
                string theURL = chordLink.OuterHtml;
                theURL = theURL.Remove(0,9);
                int startPos = theURL.IndexOf(">") - 1;

                theURL = theURL.Substring(0, startPos);

                const string theBadCode = "º";

                theChord.ChordNameURL = HTMLEncodeSpecialChars(theURL);
                theChordKey.Chords.Add(theChord);
            }

            //VARIATIONS ETC
            foreach (Chord theChord in theChordKey.Chords)
            {
                //grab the tone page
                doc = web.Load("http://www.scales-chords.com/" + theChord.ChordNameURL);

                HtmlNode chordMoreInfoTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='body']/div[@id='left']/div[@id='visit']/center/table[1]/tbody");
                HtmlNodeCollection chordMoreInfoRows = chordMoreInfoTable.SelectNodes("tr");

                theChord.Notes = chordMoreInfoRows[3].SelectNodes("td")[1].InnerText;
                theChord.Structure = chordMoreInfoRows[4].SelectNodes("td")[1].InnerText;
                theChord.BelongsTo = chordMoreInfoRows[6].SelectNodes("td")[1].InnerText;

                HtmlNodeCollection variationHTML = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='body']/div[@id='left']/div[@id='visit']/center/b");

                for (int iVariation = 1; iVariation < variationHTML.Count; iVariation=iVariation+2)
                {
                    Variation theVariation = new Variation();

                    theVariation.Notation = variationHTML[iVariation].NextSibling.InnerHtml;
                    theVariation.Difficuty = variationHTML[iVariation + 1].NextSibling.InnerText;

                    string[] theStrings = theVariation.Notation.Split(' ');
                    try
                    {
                        theVariation.String1 = theStrings[1];
                        theVariation.String2 = theStrings[2];
                        theVariation.String3 = theStrings[3];
                        theVariation.String4 = theStrings[4];
                        theVariation.String5 = theStrings[5];
                        theVariation.String6 = theStrings[6];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    theChord.Variations.Add(theVariation);

                    Console.WriteLine(theChord.ChordNameText + " : " + theVariation.Notation);
                }
            }
        }

        this.SaveToDisk("C:\\chords.xml");
    }
```

thanks

Dan

Comment: Could you post the code you use to parse the page? And the address of the actual page (if available online)?

Comment: The “question mark in a black diamond” (U+FFFD, �) that you're seeing is the [replacement glyph](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#replacement_glyph), which indicates that you attempted to decode a value not supported by the used encoding. The issue is probably a wrong encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you are having are most likely due to the encoding. The page states that they use the charset `windows-1252`, so changing your code like this should work.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
doc = web.Load(client.OpenRead("http://www.scales-chords.com/showchbykey.php?key=" + theChordKey.KeyName));
```

Of course, if you where to use this function more than once i'd move the declaration of the `WebClient` instance out of the foreach.